# Do I really need to define a variable as an array before I use it?

Tags: php, variables

I am self taught, and have always been told to define an array before I use it, e.g.

```
$example = array();

foreach($x as $y) {
    $example[] = $y;
}
```

Is this necessary? Any time I have tried to do it without, it always seems to work okay.

Comment: Necessary, no. Clearer, yes.

Comment: As you say its not actually necessary in a weakly types language like PHP **BUT** it is very good practice if for no other reason than when you come to make an amendment to this program the fact that `$example` has been defined as an array is as good as documentation.

Comment: As has been mentioned, it's good practice to set it as an array. This has caught me out in the past when I've not set it as an array and then decided that I needed to check that an array key exists. If you haven't pushed anything to the array, then you'll get warnings, 

`Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need to, but you should.

It's definitely better practice to do create the array first. It makes the code much more readable. If you don't define the variable first and somebody reads you code he might get irritated by this and possibly starts thinking he overlooked something or even he starts thinking you left something out.

The [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying) additionally state:

> If $arr doesn't exist yet, it will be created, so this is also an
>   alternative way to create an array. **This practice is however
>   discouraged because if $arr already contains some value (e.g. string
>   from request variable) then this value will stay in the place and []
>   may actually stand for string access operator.** It is always better to
>   initialize variable by a direct assignment.

Comment: seems clear. I'll just carry on defining them first :) thanks

Comment: @wumm I made a small edit to the wording of your first 2 sentences. You may also want to add that triggering any error in PHP is strongly discouraged, even when error reporting is turned off for that level. I *think* that even when error reporting is off, the errors still occur and are often logged to a file. (having many errors can slow down your system).

Comment: @user2992596 I'm glad I could clear up your doubts. If my answer helped you and you don't have any more questions please consider accepting it.

Comment: @NickJ As I just found out no warning will be triggered (even with E_ALL). So I deleted my sentence about warnings and you'll understand that it doesn't make much sense anymore to add that warnings/errors can slow down the system.

Comment: Accepted now. Had to wait a few minutes yesterday before I could accept it and had to log off before the timer was up :)